# 'java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 00' Error during new VF page creation

Tags: visualforce, exception

I am getting the following visualforce error while trying to save a new/existing visual force page.  **java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 00.**

I use Notepad++ to edit the markup. While trying to save it to the VF page sometimes I encounter this situation. Has anybody got some clue where I go wrong?

**I copy/paste the source from Notepad++ to web-based page editor.**

Below is the source for your reference. (Changed the business object names)

```
<apex:page controller="mycontroller" extensions="extone,exttwo" showheader="false" title="foo" standardstylesheets="false">
<head>
    <title>foo</title>
</head>

<!--***************** For enabling JQuery validations compatible with IE9 ***************** -->
<apex:outputText escape="false" value="{!'<meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=EmulateIE8\" />'}"/>
<apex:outputText escape="false" value="{!'<ext:ResourcePlaceHolder runat=\"client\" Mode=\"Style\" />'}"/>

<!--***************** Redirecting to foo page starts***************** -->
<form id="submitForm" name="submitForm"  method="post" action=" ">
    <input type="hidden" id="hdnfooid" name="fooid" />
    <input type="hidden" id="hdnaction" name="action" />
</form>
<!--***************** Redirecting to foo page ends ***************** -->

<apex:form id="theForm"> 

    <!--***************** Adding Page Header component starts***************** -->
    <c:PageHeader sObject="{!sec}" />

    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.Styles, 'CSS/PageStyles.css')}" />

    <div class="menu_div">
    <center>
        <div class="menu_center_div">
            <c:Menu sControlValue="{!obj}" CurrentMenuItem="foo" CId="{CId}" />
        </div>    
    </center>
    </div>
    <!--***************** Adding Page Header component ends ***************** -->

    <!--***************** CSS and for base information in all the pages (Ex: Menu, Header, cimage, etc.)***************** -->
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.Styles, 'CSS/ExportExcel.css')}" />
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.Styles, 'CSS/' + browserType + '_StyleSheet.css')}" />
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.Styles, 'CSS/' + browserType + '_HomeLayoutStyleSheet.css')}" />
    <!--***************** CSS and for base information in all the pages ends ***************** -->

    <!--***************** JQuery Framework reference starts ***************** -->
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.JQGrid, '/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js')}"  />

    <!--*****************  CSS and JavaScript files for using Jquery functionalities like grid with Paging, sorting, etc. - Starts -->
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.JQGrid, '/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js')}"  />
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.JQGrid, '/js/json2.js')}"  />
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.JQGrid, '/js/underscore-min.js')}"  />
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.JQGrid, '/js/backbone-min.js')}"  />
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.JQGrid, '/js/grid.locale-en.js')}"  />

    <!--***************** CSS and JavaScript files for using Jquery functionalities like grid with Paging, sorting, etc. - Ends -->
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.JQGrid, '/css/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.css')}"  />
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.JQGrid, '/css/ui.jqgrid.css')}"  />

    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.test, '/JS/foo.js')}"  />
    <!--***************** JQuery Framework reference starts ends ***************** -->

    <!--***************** Script Functions***************** -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        "use strict";

        //JS variable to hold the controller variable values in javascript
        var PageVariables = new Object();
        setJSVariablesWithApexVariableValues();

        //Assign controller properties to javascript object
        function setJSVariablesWithApexVariableValues()
        {
            PageVariables.sPrefix = '{!$Prefix}';
            PageVariables.selectedTab = '{!sTab}';

            SetVariableValues(PageVariables);
        }
    </script>

    <!--***************** HTML content begins ***************** -->           
    <body class="body" onload="pageload();callNavigationProperty();">                
        <center>

            <!--***************** Loading image ends ***************** -->
            <div id="loadingStatus">
                <div class="centeredAlt">
                    <img style="loadingStatusdivimg" src="{!URLFOR($Resource.Styles, 'CSS/Images/loading.gif')}" />
                    <br />
                    Loading....         
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--***************** Loading image ends ***************** -->

            <apex:pageMessages />

            <div id="companyId" class="emptydiv">{!cId}</div>
            <div id="maincontent" class="shadow shadowdiv" >
                <div id="Navcontainer">
                    <div class="Navcontainerdiv">
                        <c:SiteNavigation id="NavigationComponents" sObject="{!sec}" SelectedMenuItem="foo"/> 
                    </div>
                    <!--pnlHeader Starts-->                
                    <div class="errorbox" id="errorbox"><ul></ul></div>
                    <!--pnlHeader Ends--> 
                </div>

                <!--***************** Information Bar starts ***************** -->
                <apex:outputPanel id="errorMsg" rendered="{!RenderInfoBar}">
                    <div id="informationBar">
                        <div>
                            <apex:outputText value="{!errMsg}" styleclass="infoText"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </apex:outputPanel>
                <!--***************** Information Bar ends ***************** -->

                <!--***************** Popup panel while Requesting a foo ***************** -->   
                <div id="declinePanel" style="display:none;">
                    <div id="simplemodal-overlay" class="simplemodal-overlay" style="opacity: 0.5;filter:alpha(opacity=50); height: 100%; width: 100%; position: fixed; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 1001;"></div>
                    <div style="width:100%; float:left;">
                        <div style="width:600px; margin:0 auto;">
                            <div id="simplemodal-container" class="simplemodal-container" style="position: fixed; top:20%; z-index: 1002; height: 260px; width: 600px; margin:0 auto;">
                            <a title="Close" class="modalCloseImg modal_box_close" onclick="docCancel()"></a>
                            <div tabindex="-1" class="simplemodal-wrap" style="height: 100%; outline: 0px none; width: 100%; overflow: visible;">
                                <div style="" id="user-request-reject-dialog" class="simplemodal-data">
                                    <div id="popUpTitle" Class="popUpTitle">
                                        <span>Request a foo</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="popUpTextAreaDiv" style="margin:0px 30px 5px 0px;">
                                        <apex:inputTextarea id="popUpTextArea" cols="40" rows="20" styleClass="popUpTextArea" value="{!requestfoo}" />
                                        <apex:outputText id="popUpErrorText" style="display:none;padding:5px;color:red;" value="Please enter reason for request."></apex:outputText>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="popUpButtonDiv">
                                        <apex:commandButton id="decline_popUp_Submit" value="Submit" action="{!Requestfoo}" onclick="return fooSubmit();" style="margin-right:5px;"/>
                                        <input type="button" id="decline_popUp_Cancel" value="Cancel" class="cancel" onclick="docCancel()" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--***************** Popup panel while Requesting a foo starts***************** -->

                <!--***************** foo sub tabs starts ***************** -->

                <br /><br /><br /><br />
                <div class="inner_tabs clearfix">
                    <div id="ALL" class="inner_tab inactivetab"  onclick="j$('[id$=errorMsg]').hide();setSelectedTab('ALL');"><span >ALL ({!AllfoosCount})</span></div>
                    <div id="foo1" class="inner_tab inactivetab" style="display:{! IF((obj.View||obj.all),'block','none')};" onclick="j$('[id$=errorMsg]').hide();setSelectedTab('foo');"><span >foo ({!foocount})</span></div>               
                </div>
                <!--***************** foo sub tabs ends ***************** -->
            </div>

            <div class="fullwidth">
                <div class="fullwidth_div" >
                    <!--***************** Export to Excel starts ***************** -->   
                    <center>
                        <apex:commandLink id="ExportLink" value="Export" styleClass="ExportExcel emptydiv" onClick="setselectedtabvalue1(seltab, 'Excel');" onComplete="getJQGridurl();">  
                            <apex:actionFunction name="setselectedtabvalue1" rerender="RenderInfoBar" timeout="600000" action="{!saveExportList}" >
                                <apex:param name="selectedtab" value="" assignTo="{!selectedTab}"/>
                                <apex:param name="returnType" value="" assignTo="{!returnType}"/>
                            </apex:actionFunction>
                        </apex:commandLink>
                    </center>
                    <!--***************** Export to Excel section end ***************** -->   

                    <a class="glyphLink right fooLinkFirst" style="display:{!IF((obj.Request && Usr=='xxx'),'block','none')};" onclick="requestfoo();return false" >Request a foo</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!--***************** Tracking starts ***************** -->  
            <div class="emptydiv">
                <apex:outputPanel id="testpanel" rendered="true"></apex:outputPanel>
                <apex:actionFunction action="{!dosth}" name="dosth" rerender="testpanel" status="donesth" timeout="600000">
                    <apex:param name="fooid" assignTo="{!ID}" value="" />
                    <apex:param name="Title" assignTo="{!Name}" value="" />
                    <apex:param name="Link" assignTo="{!Link}" value="" />
                </apex:actionFunction>
                <apex:actionStatus id="donesth">
                    <apex:facet name="start"></apex:facet>
                    <apex:facet name="stop"></apex:facet>
                </apex:actionStatus>
            </div>

            <br />
            <br />
            <div id="GridDiv">

                <!--***************** Asset Grid starts ***************** -->       
                <table id="objectList"></table>
                <div id="objectListpager2"></div>

            </div>    

            <!--***************** Asset Grid ends ***************** -->
            <apex:outputpanel id="EmptyDiv" styleclass="emptydiv">
                <div class="Emptyouterdiv">
                    <div class="Emptyinnerdiv">
                    Sorry, we did not find any results. 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </apex:outputpanel>

        </center>

        <div class="footerdiv">
            <!--***************** Footer Component starts ***************** --> 
            <center>
                <div class="footerdivdiv">
                    <c:FooterMenu sControlValue="{!Obj}" CId="{!CId}" sMatrixId="{!MatrixId}" />
                </div>
            </center>
        </div>
    <!--***************** Footer Component ends ***************** -->
    </body>

    <apex:pagemessages ></apex:pagemessages>

</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Can you post your page markup? How are you synchronizing the code you edit in Notepad++ with the Visualforce page definition on the server? Are you copying/pasting into the web-based Page Editor, into Eclipse, etc.?

Comment: I dont think this is a bug from the user end, we also got the same error for couple of errors across few of our visual force pages. After couple of hours every thing seems ok again. You still getting this issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an issue in your code. I usually get a similar Null Pointer Exception error that you got.

```
Error: Java.lang.NullPointerException
Error: null
```

I tried saving the page again after a couple of minutes and it got saved.

This might work for you too.